# Facebook share show wrong image

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

I have a wordpress website. And I use Facebook share button, but share image is wrong.

Facebook choose random image from my site

My image is 600x600

Also I Try to add

```
<meta property="og:image:width" content="600" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="600" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/111.jpg"/>
```

But I still see another image.

Also I have this message from Open Graph Object Debugger (Facebook)
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Give us the URL for a live example.

Answer (score 1):

After creating the open graph tags go to facebook debugger and click on "fetch new scrape information".

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

This tells Facebook that their are new OG tags on your site and its cache will be recreated and the changes are shown than.

Make also sure that their is only one og:image tag in your site.

Comment: Yes, I clicked this button before creating this thread but unfortunately I`m still getting this error.

Comment: Do you have a url for us?